# Normal bundle of a double branched cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the double cover $\pi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ branched over a divisor $D\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ along an ample divisor $\mathcal{L}$. Then one has
$$0\rightarrow\pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}^1\rightarrow\Omega^1_S\rightarrow\Omega^1_{S/\mathbb{P}^2}\rightarrow0$$
where the support of $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2/S}$ should be the divisor $D$. How should I compute $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2/S}$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R \subset S$ be the ramification divisor. Note that the map $\pi \colon R \to D$ is an isomorphism.
Then there is a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>
\pi^*\mathcal{O}_D(-D) @>>>
\pi^*(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}\vert_D) @>>>
\pi^*\Omega_D @>>> 0
\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @.
\\
0 @>>>
\mathcal{O}_R(-R) @>>>
\Omega_S\vert_R @>>>
\Omega_R @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$
The right vertical map is an isomorphism, and the left vertical map is zero. Therefore, there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \pi^*\mathcal{O}_D(-D) \to
\pi^*(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}\vert_D) \to 
\Omega_S\vert_R \to 
\mathcal{O}_R(-R) \to 0.
$$
And since the cokernel of $\pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2} \to 
\Omega_S$ is supported on $S$, it follows that it is isomorphic to the cokernel of the restriction to $R$, that is $\mathcal{O}_R(-R)$.